# Action inside a table vs. Specific screen for the action?

Tags: usability, navigation, web-app, tables

So.. My webapp is targeted for Human Resources departament.

The app has a screen that list Positions.

Now I'll have two new requisites in the application which are:

- The user might be able to choose a Position and create one Profile for that Position.
- The user might be able to view which Positions has Profiles built, which has not.

Then my questions raises. Which approach is better?

1. Inside my Positions grid

   - Create a new column in grid with an icon named 'Build profile'
   - So the user is redirected to a new screen where it can 'Build the profile' for that Position.
   - Create a new column in grid named 'Has Profile?'. Showing Yes or No.
2. Without modify Positions grid.

   - Create a new module named 'Profiles'
   - Show a grid of Profiles created with a column named Position.
   - Let the user able to create a new Profile
   - When the user will create a new Profile, show a Dropdown with Positions.

I tend to prefer the second option, but scares me if the user has 90 positions and 34 profiles. How the user will know which is pending, and which is not... I don't know...

What do you think about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do responsive design having different views on a mobile device / tablet and lap top based on screen width.

On the narrower screen I wouldn't add the extra column, just highlight the background if there where a profile for that position. On click on a profile go to a new page showing the profile and enable editing (inline). On click where there are no profile - let the user know that she can create a profile or cancel - and return to the list.

On wider screens you can add more columns and a preview of the profiles' first 50 characters - and then a *show more...* link on the ones with a profile. The ones without profile would get an *add profile* link.

[image: Add Profile image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do a variant of what Benny suggests.  Use color or icon to differentiate be with and without profile,  provide a filter on top (a column sort seems overkill for a boolean).